# how to pass List(Of objects) - orders - from results page to details page

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview, web-applications

The context I am in is the following:

I have a page that receives a date range, from the user, then user click button and a list of orders that are retrieved from a web service, are displayed on a grid-view, having on of the columns be a hyperlink that links the order results page to the order details page, passing the order id on the query-string.

This is how the orders are retrieved:

```
Public Sub GetOrdersByDate(ByVal StartDate As Date, ByVal EndDate As Date, ByVal StrEnv As String)
    Dim client As New OrderService.OrderClient
    _items = New List(Of Order)

    Try
        client.Endpoint.Address = New EndpointAddress(Globals.AppSettings("OrderEnv" & "_" & StrEnv))

        Dim returnedServiceOrder As List(Of OrderService.OrderDataHeaderModel)
        returnedServiceOrder = client.GetOrdersByDateRange(siteKey, StartDate, EndDate)
        copyOrderServiceModelToUIModel(returnedServiceOrder)
    Catch ex As Exception
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ex.Message)
    Finally
        client.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is how the second page gets accessed from the hyperlink:

```
DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblOrderID"), HyperLink).NavigateUrl = Page.ResolveUrl("~/order-review.aspx?order_id=" & e.Row.DataItem.OrderID)
```

I need to add pagination to the order details page, and move back on forth on the set of orders that was displayed in the first page.

I am not sure how to pass the set of orders to the order details page so that I can add next, and previous buttons to change the order that is displayed on the order details page.

What are some of the common methods used to achieve this?

Many thanks

This is an example of main/ detail functionality: http://aspsnippets.com/demos/483/

But my question is, how can paging be added to the details view from the result on the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web service result (List(Of objects)), you can store that result in session.

On the next page you can filter the result from the session using OrderID you passed in the query string.

You will have one order object. It should have order items property, which is a List(Of orderItem). You can bind that list to a GridView and implement paging on GridView.

1.On the first page store web service result into session.

```
Dim returnedServiceOrder As List(Of OrderService.OrderDataHeaderModel)
returnedServiceOrder = client.GetOrdersByDateRange(siteKey, StartDate, EndDate)
Session("ServiceResult") = serviceResult
```

2.Retrieve that result from session on next page.

```
Dim returnedServiceOrder As List(Of OrderService.OrderDataHeaderModel)
returnedServiceOrder = CType(Session("ServiceResult"), List(Of OrderService.OrderDataHeaderModel))
```

Comment: would you be able to show hot to do this part?: Web service result (List(Of objects)), you can store that result in session.